# How do you get the loaded entity from a fixture DataSet class?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, fixture

I am using [fixture](https://github.com/fixture-py/fixture) to load testing data using ndb for my Google App Engine project using [this patch](https://github.com/fixture-py/fixture/pull/18). Inside my unit tests I often need to reference the underlying entity which causes me to do things like:

```
# MyEntityClass is an ndb.Model subclass
# MyEntityClassData is a fixture.DataSet
entity = MyEntityClass.get_by_id(MyEntityClassData.entity_one.id_field)
```

This just feels dirty. Is there a way to extract the entity class created for `MyEntityClassData.entity_one` directly from the fixture class?

Comment: The fixture class contains references to entities in the form of ids. You're getting the entity using a get_by_id on that id. I can't think of a more straightforward way of doing it. What's dirty about that?

Comment: I guess you're right. I found references under a long object graph starting with `datasetinstance.data.meta.datasets` but I thought it would be more straightforward. The `with_data` decorator will pass them into your test method but it switches the order between `self` and your entities.